# Code behind web methods vs. javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

What are the pros/cons of using c# code behind instead of javascript to change contents of an asp.net/html page? Specifically, I was wondering which would be better if I get a JSON object from a different server through a button click and then have to fill in that JSON object's contents into a table and then sort that table.

Also, a user could request multiple objects which would mean appending multiple tables to the same page without reloading the page. Would code behind allow this or is javascript the better option here?

Comment: ASP.Net Web Form or ASP.Net MVC?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Let me clarify. The API that I am calling is represented as model and controller and the view is separated as a asp.net webpage on a separate server. I am talking about using javascript vs. code behind for the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pros for WebMethods/WebServices/WebAPIs in providing content for a web page:

- You have more resources at your disposal for processing requests, for example, you can access data stored in the filesystem or in a DB, process it and return it in a variety of formats such as XLS, CSV, JSON, Images, Strings, Binary blobs, etc.
- You can handle your application's security in a better way since the code is not exposed and is not editable, also diminishing the posibilities for glitches and bugs.
- You can leverage larger computing power than you would have on the average computer that's sending the request

Cons for WebMethods/WebServices/WebApis:

- The response time will always be higher since requests are sent through the network and all the possible roadblocks apply: latency, network traffic, packet loss, server load, etc.
- Large workloads require more complex logic for requests processing and it will consume more resources, resulting in higher costs for maintaining the application
- The technologies used will usually involve more complexity than using just client side technologies (C#, ASP.NET, MVC, SQL, WCF, etc vs JavaScript, HTML and CSS)

Pros for client-side technologies:

- They are lightweight (relatively) and possibly easier to learn and use than server side technologies
- The response time can be faster than sending requests to a server provided the operation can be performed without using resources located remotely (for example, creating a chart and saving it as an image does not necessarily require you to send data to the server)
- Lots of platforms can be targeted since these technologies are supported by the majority of browsers
- For your specific case, DOM manipulation is faster when done in the client side, AJAX is the evidence of how much people hated postbacks and roundtrips to the server for trivial things.

Cons for client-side technologies:

- Trying to process some operations that are better suited for a server-side operation results in convoluted and sometimes unpractical solutions due to unavailability of things like access to the filesystem and other local machine resources (HTML5 helps a lot in this with the addition of Local Storage, Local DB and other resources for manipulating binary strings as data but the adoption levels for HTML5 browsers are still not where everyone want them). Specific example: I once had to create a dashboard using only jQuery, HTML and CSS due to unavailability of server side resources, i was also required to render these charts as images to allow saving, and then allow the dashboard values to be exported to Excel, all of this while supporting all browsers back to Internet Explorer 8. Needless to say, the solution was a mix of multiple scripts, plugins and use of dreadful things like ActiveX objects that ultimately get the job done, but complicate your life beyond necessity. (There is of course the issue of practicity overlooked during application design but i had no say in this)
- The execution can be slower than a request sent to a server for complex calculations that will perform different depending on the underlying hardware and available resources
- Your code is exposed and open for examination and can also be edited on the fly. Debugging client side code is also not a very pleasant experience, though progress keeps being done on this front every day.

At the end of the day, i think there are no best/worst technology, just tools better suited for a specific type of job. If you need to work with objects and data available from the client side, JS + HTML + CSS is the way to go, but if you need to persist and manipulate data stored outside of the client machine or perform complex calculations that require lots of processing power, then server side technologies are better suited for this task.

Answer (score 0):

In a single sentence: `ASP.NET` code behind (C#) is a server-side technology, while javascript (or jQuery) is a client-side technology. The first one is much more robust and client platform-independent, while a second one provides much better responsiveness (no need for round trip to web-server). For any business-critical data operations (especially if security is a major concern) server-side technology (i.e. ASP.NET/C#) is a preferred one.

Regarding your second Q in comments: In case you need to persist any data you can use either `ViewState` ot `SessionState` objects (also, objects/methods in global.asax file).

Also, valuable addition to `ASP.NET` is `AJAX` technology (Microsoft VS implements so-called `UpdatePanel` control, which greatly simplifies the implementation of AJAX pertinent to ASP.NEt pages), which improves the responsiveness of `ASP.NET` web pages.

Rgds,

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that ASP.NET can't change static elements on the html page. Is this true? So if I wanted to append tables on button click without reloading the page, would code behind permit this? I would have to reload all data every time correct?

Comment: Asp.Net runs on the server, it can do anything you want - but you need to go back to the server. That means either a page refresh or an Ajax request for data that you then put onto the page with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally I prefer `ASP.NET Web API` , meaning get all the data from server through `JSON` over `REST`ful services , once you have your data , your `JS/Jquery` should manipulate your `HTML` or `DOM` . Both work inclusive rather than exclusive , for your data, security you have to rely on server . client side data shouldn't be heavy and should not disclose any `PII`. See `JqueryGrid` for dynamic table manipulations , there are many more client rich controls .